# Как отдельный код для пароля вставить в основной код?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, консоль

Подскажите как связать парольную защиту, для аргументов?
Необходима защита аргументов по паролю, допустим вводим `C:\>app.exe password /off` и выполняется сначала отправка пароля, если он верный, выполняется команда `/off` (все одной строчкой).

Может есть возможность как-то встроить пароль к имени аргументов? Так как нужно, чтобы ярлык приложения содержал и пароль и аргументы, для использования планировщика заданий.

Сам пароль будет храниться в текстовом документе, см.пример кода ниже.

> Уточнение вопроса: как отдельный код для пароля вставить в основной
>   код?

Основной код WinForm приложения C#

```
static class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AttachConsole(int procid);
    /// <summary>
    /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var form = new Form1();
        bool needRun = true;

        AttachConsole(-1);

        string outputFmt = "Команда {0} выполнена" + "\n" + "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .";
        List<string> cmds = new List<string>();

        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            if (args.Contains("/?"))
            {
                form.Check00();
                needRun = false;
            }
            switch (arg)
            {
                case "/on":
                    form.Check01();
                    needRun = false;
                    break;

                case "/off":
                    form.Check02();
                    needRun = false;
                    break;
            }
            cmds.Add(arg);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(outputFmt, string.Join(" ", cmds.ToArray()));
        if (needRun)
        {
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Отдельный код парольной защиты (который не получается связать):

```
    private class ConsolePassword
    {
        public ConsolePassword()
        {
            string password, password1 = string.Empty;

            password = Console.ReadLine();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open("C:\\1.txt", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                password1 = sr.ReadLine();
                sr.Close();
            }
            if (password == password1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Доступ разрешен.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Доступ запрещен.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит переделать метод `ConsolePassword` чтобы он принимал в качестве аргумента введённый пароль и проверял бы его правильность. Мне кажется, переменную `password1` лучше было бы назвать `real_password`. Не совсем понятно, в чём заключается вопрос

Comment: @mymedia нужно отдельный код для пароля вставить в основной код, в этом весь и вопрос, как это сделать :) у меня не получается их связать...

Comment: Вам нужно переформулировать или изменить вопрос. Вы хотите получить ответ на это: "Как защитить выполнение аргументов паролем?" или же на это: "Уточнение вопроса: как отдельный код для пароля вставить в основной код?"?

Comment: @Bulson сути это не меняет, задача в том, чтобы аргументы были защищены паролем.

Comment: Это для вас сути не меняет. А для сайта, на котором вы задаете вопрос это важно, т.к. формируется база знаний, а потому будьте любезны сформулировать свой вопрос однозначно понимаемым образом.

Comment: Какой смысл в таком пароле?

Comment: @vp_arth нужно, чтобы при запуске любого батника, зловредного, не прописалась команда до приложения, и не был использован аргумент `/off`, чтобы тот кто может попытаться отключить настройки приложения не смог этого сделать в командной строке, так как путь до приложения будет статичным. На данный момент любым батником можно отключить настройки приложения, поэтому и нужна защита аргументов.

Comment: А злой хакер не может взять пароль из ярлыка, в котором он будет прописан?

Comment: @vp_arth до ярлыка будет динамический путь, или выбранный пользователем. К примеру `F:\YYHgfy82i\rye63W6r.lnk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша задумка, как бы это сказать, немного странная (подумайте, может стоит хотя бы зашифровать пароль в файле, а не хранить его в открытом виде). Но если очень хочется, то вот можно такой вариант использовать. Класс для считывания пароля из файла и проверки пароля такой

```
public static class ConsolePassword
{
    //Fields
    private const string _PasswordFile = @"C:\1.txt";

    /// <summary>
    /// Проверка пароля
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">строка пароля для проверки</param>
    /// <returns>true if OK</returns>
    public static bool CheckPassword(string password)
    {
        //проверка параметра
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(password));

        //считываем пароль для сравнения из файла
        string origPassword = GetPasswordFromFile();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(origPassword)) return false;

        //сравниваем и отдаем результат
        return origPassword.Equals(password);
    }

    private static string GetPasswordFromFile()
    {
        try
        {
            //если у вас в этом файле всего одна строка с паролем
            //то проще всего прочитать так
            string result = File.ReadAllText(_PasswordFile);

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Ошибка чтения файла {ex.Message}");
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда воспользоваться этим классом можно так

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //как-то вы там получаете от пользователя пароль
        string password = "???";

        //проверяете и делаете остальное
        if (ConsolePassword.CheckPassword(password))
        {
            //пароль прошел проверку
        }
        else
        {
            //пароль не прошел проверку
            Console.WriteLine("Пароль не верен!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `string password = "???";` как можно обойтись без этого способа? Чтобы пользователь менял пароль в текстовом документе, а то придется каждому пользователю свой пароль придумывать внутри приложения? Или же есть способ менять это свойство через форму?

Comment: Bulson и получается, что пароль для аргументов не нужно вводить, он внутри приложения и сравнивается с содержимым текстового файла.

Comment: Кстати, имело бы смысл брать часть пароля из приложения и часть из текстового файла. А так, можно хоть в реестре проверять пароль.

Comment: @Vitokhv я попытался ответить на вопрос: " как отдельный код для пароля вставить в основной код?" Путем переписывания вашего класса `ConsolePassword` c последующим примером того, как его можно использовать. Это все. Ваша задумка по запуску программы с проверкой пароля из текстового файла в принципе мне не нравится по причине своей изначальной лажовости. Но если вы все таки желаете довести дело до конца, продумывайте сами дальше алгоритм получения пароля и проч. Задавайте вопросы (не в комментариях к этому ответу), кто чем сможет - поможет вам.